# Print lists Advanced

Tags: python, list

I have seven lists from A to G. I read in an input `n`, for example: `b1`. What is the fastest way to print item at index `1` in list `B`?
I have already tried this but it seems too long:

```
n = input()
if n[0].upper == 'A':
    print(A[n[1]])
elif n[0].upper == 'B':
    print(B[n[1]])
elif n[0].upper == 'C':
    print(C[n[1]])

and so on ....
```

Is there any other way of doing this? And yeah this doesn't work:

```
print(n[0].upper()[n[1]])
```

Comment: Is the input you read related to the name of list and item index in the same list?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead.  That is `{'A': [...], 'B': [...], ...}`.  That way, you can say `dictionary_name[n[0]][n[1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the correct way would be to organize your lists into the dictionary and then use it like this:

```
>>> A = [0, 1, 2]
>>> B = [3, 4, 5]
>>> data = {'A':A, 'B':B}
>>> data['B'][1]
4
```

or, in your case:

```
>>> data[n[0].upper()][n[1]]
4
```

Comment: Should be `int(n[1])`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to minimize the nr of lines to print, you can store the lists in a dictionary. Looks like you know the list indices wont exceed 10, else n[1] wont be sufficient

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> 
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> c = [7,8,9]
>>> 
>>> my_dict['a'] = a
>>> my_dict['b'] = b
>>> my_dict['c'] = c
>>>
>>> n='a1'
>>> print my_dict[n[0]][int(n[1])]
```

But before that it should be your responsibility to check if the entered list and indices exists.

Comment: Avoid naming your variables with built-in names like `dict` ... you will shadow the `dict` constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#globals) method of python. Try this:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
C = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
D = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]

n = input()
n, i = n[0].upper(), int(n[1])

print(globals()[n][i])
```

If your variables are local to a function or any other scope, you can use the little brother of `globals()` which is [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals). Like so:

```
print(locals()[n][i])
```

By the way, you said *position*, but you are using as index. Definitely item at *position* 1 is at *index* 0. You may want to clarify that bit a little more. :)